# Select Slide Layout in R Markdown PowerPoint Export

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, knitr

I create a PowerPoint with R markdown.

```
---
title: "Presentation Title"
author: "That is me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
output:
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
    slide_level: 2
---
```

As you see, I use a custom template file `template.pptx`.

Now my goal ist to select which layout to be used from that template. I know that `officedown` allows for a chunk option `layout` (see https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2021-07-officedown/), but I think it is possible without the additional package as well. Why?

When I put a table on the page via `kable`, the layout "Content with Caption" from the template is used.

````
```{r results="asis"}
cat("\n\n## Page Title\n\n")
cat("\n\nSome content\n\n")
data.frame(matrix(c(1))) %>% kable
```
````

When I use `flextable` instead, the layout "Title and Content" is used.

````
```{r results="asis", ft.left=0.9}
cat("\n\n## Page Title\n\n")
cat("\n\nSome content\n\n")
flextable(data.frame(matrix(c(1)))) %>% flextable_to_rmd
```
````

So it seems that `kable()` can somehow tell the output to use the other layout. Any ideas why that is the case?

The [Pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html?pandocs-markdown#powerpoint-layout-choice) says

> Content with Caption
>
> This layout is used for any non-two-column slides which contain text followed by non-text (e.g. an image or a table).

So that probably means that the `flextable` is not recognizes as "non-text" content. Can I add non-text content that won't show up in the presentation? It's not that I wish back times of the `clearpixel.gif`, but ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not especially proud of this, but the good old clearpixel does the job...

````
```{r results="asis", ft.left=0.9}
cat("\n\n## Page Title\n\n")
cat("\n\nSome content\n\n")
flextable(data.frame(matrix(c(1)))) %>% flextable_to_rmd
cat("![](clearpixel.png)\n")
```
````

Whoever finds a cleaner solution (the invisible elemente will still be selectable in the PPT file), please kindly post it here :)